# PerformanceWarning: DataFrame is highly fragmented. This is usually the result of calling `frame.insert` many times, which has poor performance.'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, warnings

I have a dataframe that each row is a pixel and each column indicate a feature map. So here is the case: I have a column call "pix" that can be seperate into row, col. I can use this to add column to this dataframe as I have couple of features yet to be joined. I import each map and transfer them into matrixs

So I use code pseudo-code like this to add columns:

```py
for i in tqdm(df_new.index):
            row = int(ds.pix[i][1:-1].split(',')[0])
            col = int(ds.pix[i][1:-1].split(',')[1])
            df_new[i, 'Aridity'] = arr3[row, col]
            df_new[i, 'Trend in PDSI'] = arr4[row, col]
            df_new[i, 'rainfall seasonality'] = arr5[row, col]
            df_new[i, 'Precipitation variability'] = arr6[row, col]
            df_new[i, 'Trend in Precipitation'] = arr7[row, col]
            df_new[i, 'rainfall at coldest quarter'] = arr8[row, col]
            df_new[i, 'rainfall at hottest quarter'] = arr9[row, col]
            df_new[i, 'Temperature seasonality'] = arr10[row, col]
            df_new[i, 'Elevation'] = arr11[row, col]
            df_new[i, 'Depth of water table'] = arr12[row, col]
            df_new[i, 'Depth to bedrock'] = arr13[row, col]
```

And I get warnings as the tilte shows. I have like more than 40000 rows.the processing speed is pretty slow. `tqdm` evaluate it more than 30 mins.

This is how I solve the problem: I change my code a little bit as shown below, the warning disapear, and the speed is 10 times faster than before. Wish this can help others. I would be appreciated if anyone has more beautiful solvement.

```py
for i in tqdm(df_new.index):
            row = int(ds.pix[i][1:-1].split(',')[0])
            col = int(ds.pix[i][1:-1].split(',')[1])
            df_new['Aridity'][i] = arr3[row, col]
            df_new['Trend in PDSI'][i]= arr4[row, col]
            df_new['rainfall seasonality'][i] = arr5[row, col]
            df_new['Precipitation variability'][i] = arr6[row, col]
            df_new['Trend in Precipitation'][i] = arr7[row, col]
            df_new['rainfall at coldest quarter'][i] = arr8[row, col]
            df_new['rainfall at hottest quarter'][i] = arr9[row, col]
            df_new['Temperature seasonality'][i] = arr10[row, col]
            df_new['Elevation'][i] = arr11[row, col]
            df_new['Depth of water table'][i] = arr12[row, col]
            df_new['Depth to bedrock'][i] = arr13[row, col]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second aproach is better because it avoids adding columns one by one, but accessing pandas DataFrame cells directly with indexing like `df_new['Aridity'][i]` is slow.

To have something performant lets compute all of the new columns first, then assign them to the DataFrame all at once.

For example:

```
aridity_values = []
trend_in_pdsi_values = []

for pix in tqdm(df_new['pix']):
    row, col = map(int, pix[1:-1].split(','))
    aridity_values.append(arr3[row, col])
    trend_in_pdsi_values.append(arr4[row, col])

df_new['Aridity'] = aridity_values
df_new['Trend in PDSI'] = trend_in_pdsi_values
```

Comment: Thanks for the interpretation, and the performance after applying your code really shocked me.  the speed evaluation changed from 300 it/s to 120000 it/s. it tooks 3min previously, now it's within 1 sec. QAQ